# How can I reshape my dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a huge data frame, that in a simple version it looks like this:

```
    trials=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10")
    co =c(rep ("1",10))
    stim=c("8","9","11","2","4","7","8","1","12","16")
    ansbin=c("1","0","1","0","0","1","0","1","1","0")
    stim.1=c("11","2","11","7","4","3","9","1","4","16")
    ansbin.1=c("0","0","1","0","0","1","0","1","1","1")
    trials.1=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10")
    co.1 =c(rep ("2",10))
    stim1.1=c("11","2","11","2","5","7","8","15","17","10")
    ansbin1.1=c("1","1","1","0","0","1","1","1","0","1")
    stim2.1=c("11","2","14","1","4","8","9","10","4","12")
    ansbin2.1=c("0","1","1","0","0","1","0","0","1","0")
    ID<-     data.frame(trials,co,stim,ansbin,stim.1,ansbin.1,trials.1,co.1,stim1.1,ansbin1.1,stim2.1,ansbin2.1)

    View(ID)
```

Now I would like to form my new data.frame in the way that "stim", "stim.1","stim1.1" and "stim2.1" are under the same column called "stimulus", and the same thing for the answers: I would like all "ansbin", "ansbin.1", "ansbin1.1" and "ansbin2.1" under the same column called "answers".
Trials and Trials.1 at the same time should be under the same column, but the difference will the "co" column.

I tryied to use "reshape" like this:

```
     df<-reshape(ID, direction="long",
           idvar=c("trials", "co"),
           varying= c("stim","stim.1",    "stim1.1","stim2.1","ansbin","ansbin.1","ansbin1.1","ansbin2.1"
           v.names=c("stimulus","answer"),
           timevar="num",
```

)

but I have some problems and warning at the everytimes. I think it should be a problem linked to columns's name.

Can you help me? 
Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I would take:

```
library(data.table)
melt(
  rbindlist(split.default(ID, cumsum(grepl("^trials", names(ID))))), 
  measure.vars = patterns("^stim", "^ansbin"), value.name = c("stim", "ansbin"))
#     trials co variable stim ansbin
#  1:      1  1        1    8      1
#  2:      2  1        1    9      0
#  3:      3  1        1   11      1
#  4:      4  1        1    2      0
#  5:      5  1        1    4      0
# ---                               
# 36:      6  2        2    8      1
# 37:      7  2        2    9      0
# 38:      8  2        2   10      0
# 39:      9  2        2    4      1
# 40:     10  2        2   12      0
```

---

Basically, it sounds like you're looking at two rounds of "reshaping".

1. Stacking the columns from "trials" to the second set of "ansbin" on top of each other. I've done that with the `rbindlist(split.default(...))` part of my answer.
2. Stacking each resulting pair of "stim" and "ansbin" columns on top of each other. I've done that with the `melt(...)` part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider building a list of reshaped dataframes for each set: *co*, *trials*, *stimulus*, and *answers*, then merge them together. However, because *co* and *trials* only carry two columns while latter two carries four columns consider repeating columns prior to reshaping:

```
ID$co2 <- ID$co
ID$co3 <- ID$co.1

ID$trials.2 <- ID$trials
ID$trials.3 <- ID$trials.1

df_list <- lapply(c("co", "trials", "stim", "ans"), function(s)      
  reshape(ID, direction="long",
          varying= grep(s, names(ID)),
          v.names=c(s),
          drop = grep(paste0("^", s), names(ID), invert=TRUE),
          timevar="num",
          new.row.names = 1:1000)      
)

# CHAIN MERGE
finaldf <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y,  by=c('id', 'num')), df_list)
finaldf <- with(finaldf, finaldf[order(num, id),])    # SORT DATAFRAME
rownames(finaldf) <- NULL                             # RESET ROWNAMES 

head(finaldf)
#   id num co trials stim ans
# 1  1   1  1      1    8   1
# 2  2   1  1      2    9   0
# 3  3   1  1      3   11   1
# 4  4   1  1      4    2   0
# 5  5   1  1      5    4   0
# 6  6   1  1      6    7   1
```